# How to gain the precise file creation time in Python?

Tags: python

I know that

```
time.time()
```

can be used to make the time system more precise and

```
time.ctime(os.stat("c:/a1.txt").st_ctime)
```

can be used to get the creation time of the file. But it can the precision is too low, only to the unit of second.

Can these two ways be combined together?

Comment: If you generate the file by yourself, then you could always add the milliseconds as part of your file name

Comment: That file is not generated by me. @lan

Comment: Sadly not, as far as I am aware, you would need to specify precise timings yourself in the files, and if they were not specified, you will have to make do with that precision. If you tell us the context, or link to a new question outlining your problem, we could take a look at some kind of workaround.

Comment: actually, that is a .tif file, and it is copyed by a widget to a certain folder (e.g. C:/) . Under windows explorer the precision is too low so I want to use Python to solve this problem cause further I need to rename the .tif files according to their creation time in the folder C:/                             @That One Random Scrub

Comment: Well sadly the .tif format of the tag DateTime follows "YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS", and that means there is no way to get a timing more precise than within the accuracy of a second. There could be a second file with the precise timing put together with it, but this won't work for a file you haven't generated/created. There is no answer here (As far as I am aware), but from what I [Read off the Interne-](http://www.awaresystems.be/imaging/tiff/tifftags/datetime.html), I MEAN know, you are sadly out of luck

Comment: Unless you keep track of or can figure it out by some other means, you're stuck with the meta-information the OS provides.

Comment: I found a way, use     os.stat("C:/a1.tif").st_ctime_ns can gain nanoseconds level    @That One Random Scrub

Comment: Well I have been proven a moron once again, I suppose this question is closed.

Comment: Don't be so depress, I am also a beginner @That One Random Scrub

Comment: @miata You can go ahead and answer your own question, and accept the answer too to help out future people. :)

Comment: Windows file time is not as accurate as you think. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284(v=vs.85).aspx "on NT FAT, create time has a resolution of 10 milliseconds, write time has a resolution of 2 seconds, and access time has a resolution of 1 day (really, the access date)."

Comment: Some answers do not require the code so I don't know how to choose the best answer and close that:)  @JETM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use os.stat("C:/a1.tif").st_ctime_ns can gain nanoseconds level